# how would I use iphone motion detection for an egg shaking-like application?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, motion-detection

I am hoping to build an application similar to those egg shaking applications, to better understand how to detect motion on the iphone. I've been looking at accelerometer methods and motion and motion methods, but can't seem to get working what I want to do.

The specifics of my need are as follows: I want to be able to play one sound when user shakes the phone away from them, and play another sound when they shake back towards them. The motion from the user would be very similar to an egg shaker, with two different sounds able to be played depending on whether they moved the device towards or away from their chest. It would also be good to measure the intensity with which they moved away or towards.

Any ideas?

I've searched apple's sample code for a similar application, but there doesnt seem to be one.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this game which is open source and makes great use of the accelerometer.  It's a good one to be able to tell which direction you are going, but I haven't messed around much with intensity.  I'm sure it's easy enough once you get into the details.

http://github.com/haqu/tweejump